# muzei - FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[TaskQueueService]

Tags: android, muzei

I'm trying to create an art source ( plugin ) for muzei.

The app is supposed to provide a new art source which in my case is a folder of my app-private space.

Following the example from the muzei api [here](http://api.muzei.co/reference/com/google/android/apps/muzei/api/Artwork.Builder.html)  and the details it provides [here](http://api.muzei.co/reference/com/google/android/apps/muzei/api/Artwork.Builder.html#imageUri%28android.net.Uri%29)  I created a FileProvider for my app.

I have added this code to my manifest :

```
           <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.foo.bar.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/muzei_wallpapers" />
          </provider>
```

I created the xml file `muzei_wallpapers` in my res/xml folder :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="my_images" path="files/"  />
</paths>
```

and as you can see it points to my `files/` folder.

And last is my class that extends `MuzeiArtSource` :

```
public class MuzeiService extends MuzeiArtSource {

Uri imgUri;


public MuzeiService() {
    super(MuzeiService.class.getName());
}


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
   // setUserCommands(BUILTIN_COMMAND_ID_NEXT_ARTWORK); // manual switch image         
}

@Override
protected void onUpdate(int arg0) {

       imgUri = muzeiContentUri();  

    publishArtwork(new Artwork.Builder()
           .imageUri( Uri.parse("imgUri") )
           .title("Example image")
           .byline("Unknown person, c. 1980")
           .build());       
}



public Uri muzeiContentUri()    {
    File imagePath = new File(getFilesDir(), "files");
    File newFile = new File(imagePath, "wallpaper0.png");
    Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), "com.foo.bar.fileprovider", newFile);

    return contentUri;
}



}
```

Which seems to me the simplest example I can have returning the uri for a simple file ( named wallpapaper0 )

When I select as resource for muzei my app I get an "unfortunately muzei has stopped" and the logcat is :

```
      05-28 04:29:40.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3670): FATAL EXCEPTION:      IntentService[TaskQueueService]
05-28 04:29:40.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3670): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-28 04:29:40.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3670):     at      com.google.android.apps.muzei.util.IOUtil.readFullyWriteToOutputStream(IOUtil.java:210)
 05-28 04:29:40.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3670):    at      com.google.android.apps.muzei.util.IOUtil.readFullyWriteToFile(IOUtil.java:202)
05-28 04:29:40.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3670):     at      com.google.android.apps.muzei.ArtworkCache.maybeDownloadCurrentArtworkSync(ArtworkCache.java:122)
05-28 04:29:40.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3670):     at      com.google.android.apps.muzei.TaskQueueService.onHandleIntent(TaskQueueService.java:56)
05-28 04:29:40.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3670):     at     android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
05-28 04:29:40.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3670):     at     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-28 04:29:40.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3670):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-28 04:29:40.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3670):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

I would really appreciate any help cause I'm stuck with it the last days and I feel like  I'm missing something simple here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing in `Uri.parse("imgUri")` - you should just be passing in `imgUri`:

```
imgUri = muzeiContentUri();  

publishArtwork(new Artwork.Builder()
       .imageUri(imgUri)
       .title("Example image")
       .byline("Unknown person, c. 1980")
       .build());
```

Comment: if I change this I get : `The method parse(String) in the type Uri is not applicable for the arguments (Uri)`

Comment: You did look at the code I posted right? You already created a Uri so you don't need to do any parsing.